# Integrator type in order to solve the differential equations

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Does anyone know which integrator type (e.g. implicit Euler) is used in Gazebo, respectively ODE, in order to solve the differential equations?

Best
Nils

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17349/integrator-type-in-order-to-solve-the-differential-equations/) by [NRottmann](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3368/nrottmann/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo uses ODE as physics engine by default and ODE uses [semi-implicit Euler integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-implicit_Euler_method).
Bullet uses semi-implicit Euler integration as well.

---

Originally posted by [Ying Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1156/ying-lu/) with karma: 36 on 2017-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NRottmann](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3368/nrottmann/) on 2017-10-02**:
Hi, thanks for your answer. Do you know where I can find some paper or something else where the integrator type of the ODE is described?

**Comment by [Ying Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1156/ying-lu/) on 2017-10-04**:
You can probably refer to this webpage: http://wiki.ros.org/physics_ode/ODE  although the latex display is bad, but you might get an idea.

If you are looking for how the time stepper is working, refer to my thesis here https://foswiki.cs.rpi.edu/foswiki/pub/RoboticsWeb/LabPublications/YLu_thesis.pdf
In chapter 3, From basic equation of motion (3.1), you can jump to equation (3.27) Hopefully section 3.3 in this thesis will give you some reference as well